# multiple nested collection fields & sonata_type_collection

Tags: symfony, collections, admin, sonata

I'm pretty new to sonata admin bundle, and I could use some help.

Problem:

I have a Quiz entity, a Question entity, an Answer entity.

Relationship between Quiz and Question: one to many.

Quiz Entity

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Question", mappedBy="quiz", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
protected $questions;
```

Question Entity

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Quiz", inversedBy="questions", cascade={"persist"})
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="quiz_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable = false)
*/
protected $quiz;
```

Relationship Question and Answer: one to many.

Question Entity

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="question", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
*/
protected $answers;
```

Answer Entity

```
/**
* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="question_id", referencedColumnName="id")
*/
protected $question;
```

I need a form where I can add multiple questions to a lesson and each question can have one or multiple answers, these answers should also have a true or false flag.

So basically I need something like this:
[mockup](https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-NOjgSNMsJP8/VFok4zx5UMI/AAAAAAAAAAo/m1smJb039lI/s1600/questions.png)

So far I managed to make work only adding multiple questions from the admin. Actually a couple of versions ago (both sonata admin and doctrine) I had both questions and answers working. But now I can only add multiple questions while I can't add any answers.

This is my QuestionType class:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class QuestionType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder
            ->add('text', 'text', array( 'required' => false, 'label' => 'question' ) )
            ->add('answers', 'collection', array(
                    'type'               => new AnswerType(),
                    'allow_add'          => true,
                    'allow_delete'       => true,
                    'by_reference'       => false,
                    'delete_empty'       => true,
                    'cascade_validation' => false,
                    'label'              => 'Answers',
                    'options'            => array( 'label' => false ),
                    'label_attr'         => array( 'class' => 'answers' ),
            ));
    }


    public function getName()
    {
        return 'questions';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions( OptionsResolverInterface $resolver )
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults( array(
            'data_class' => MyBundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Question',
        ));
    }

}
```

This is my AnswerType class:

```
<?php

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class AnswerType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm( FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options )
    {
        $builder
            ->add('text', 'text', array( 'required' => true, 'label' => 'answer' ) )
            ->add('correct', 'checkbox', array( 'required' => false ) );
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'answers';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions( OptionsResolverInterface $resolver )
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults( array(
            'data_class' => 'MyBundle\CoreBundle\Entity\Answer',
        ));
    }

}
```

This is my QuizAdmin class:

```
<?php 

use MyBundle\CoreBundle\Form\QuestionType;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Route\RouteCollection;

class QuizAdmin extends Admin
{

    // Fields to be shown on create/edit forms
    protected function configureFormFields( FormMapper $formMapper )
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('title', 'text', array( 'label' => 'Quiz Title' ) )
            ->add('description', 'textarea', array( 'label' => 'Quiz Description' ) )
            ->add('private', 'checkbox', array('required' => false ) )
            ->add('questions', 'collection', array(
                    'type'               => new QuestionType(),
                    'allow_add'          => true,
                    'allow_delete'       => true,
                    'cascade_validation' => false,
                    'by_reference'       => false,
                    'delete_empty'       => true,
                    'options'            => array( 'label' => false ),
            ));
    }

    // Fields to be shown on filter forms
    protected function configureDatagridFilters( DatagridMapper $datagridMapper )
    {
        $datagridMapper
            ->add( 'title' );
    }

    // Fields to be shown on lists
    protected function configureListFields( ListMapper $listMapper )
    {
        $listMapper
            ->addIdentifier( 'title' );
    }
}
```

I have also tried using sonata_type_collection but it does not work it returns this error:
"The current field "questions" is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity"
I've looked this up and tried everything that was suggested on stackoverflow but I could not get it working. 
I would very much appreciate any advice on this matter.

And this is how the admin page for the quiz currently looks like with questions and answers:

[sample](https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-xXqsY_P2_NI/VFenI3YDOvI/AAAAAAAAAAY/-eAO-d30FZQ/s1600/Selection_003.png)

As I mentioned before some couple of versions ago before running composer.phar update I could add both questions and answers ( I do not remember the versions, but then I had some other problems with unique fields, I was happy that got fixed, but now I have this problem).

If you have any advice I would be happy to follow.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have also a Quizz system in my project and i have the same entity as you have.

You have to create the controller and admin for each entity:

- Quizz: QuizzAdmin / QuizzController
- Question: QuestionAdmin / QuestionController
- Answer: AnswerAdmin / AnswerController

This will fix your error : The current field "questions" is not linked to an admin. Please create one for the target entity.

I am using sonata_type_collection as the field type and you have to use this gist: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/1971/files, otherwise you won't be able to add answers.

You just have to change your field answers to match the one in my classes.

QuizzAdmin:

```
class QuizzAdmin extends Admin
{
    protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
    {
         $formMapper->add('questions', 'sonata_type_collection',
             array(
                 'by_reference' => false
             ),
             array(
                 'edit' => 'inline',
                 'inline' => 'table'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

QuestionAdmin:

```
class QuestionAdmin
{
    protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper->add('answers', 'sonata_type_collection',
            array(
                'by_reference' => false
             ),
             array(
                 'edit' => 'inline',
                 'inline' => 'table'
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Also you should consider adding in your Admin classes the following code so that your assert validation on question and answer are triggered when you add a Quizz in the Admin:

```
class QuizzAdmin extends Admin 
{
    protected $formOptions = array(
        'cascade_validation' => true
    );
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm doing something very similar to this with nested 'sonata_type_collection', but i'm having an issue, I'm using the gist mentioned in the answer. When I have only one collection everything displays just fine, but when I nest them the childrens of the first collection disappear. Do you have any idea why (also there is an error in your quizadmin class, you've used the method configureListFields, it should be configureFormFields, and the edit queue is full)

Answer (score 0):

Hi my friends it my first answer and I hope it well by useful.
How can I do nested collection for few lewel:
1) create AnswerType 
2) don`t create QuestionType
3) in QuestionAdmin use collection AnswerType
4) in QuizAdmin use sonata_type_collection for Question Entity